# Mouse scrolling in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use `mouse scroll` to make circle bigger (`mouse-scroll-up`) and circle smaller (`mouse-scroll-down`).

I have existing code to change circle radius smaller already with mouse middle button, but my question would be:

> How can I use mouse-scroll-up and mouse-scroll-down to do the same thing?

I have googled, it could be done somehow with `ScrollEvent`, but I can't understand  this very well.

Comment: Are you familiar with events and event handlers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering to your question

> How can I use mouse-scroll-up and mouse-scroll-down to do the same thing?

- Use a `ScrollListener` on the circle and use the [ScrollEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html) reference to get the `DeltaY`.
- Create a `zoomfactor` to calculate the zoom factor you want to have.
- Apply this factor to the Scale property of your node.

**Complete Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ZoomInOutCircles extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dots");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Circle circle = new Circle(175, 150, 10, Color.BLUE);
        addMouseScrolling(circle);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void addMouseScrolling(Node node) {
        node.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            // Adjust the zoom factor as per your requirement
            double zoomFactor = 1.05;
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
            if (deltaY < 0){
                zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
            }
            node.setScaleX(node.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
            node.setScaleY(node.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
        });
    }
}
```