# How to handle the mouse wheel scrolling event using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, java-8

Just need to get some numeric equivalent, which will show how much the wheel is scrolled.

I managed to find an example only using awt/swing: [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MouseWheelEventDemoProject/src/events/MouseWheelEventDemo.java)

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you take a look at the javadoc of `ScrollEvent`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse scrolling in Java FX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735651/mouse-scrolling-in-java-fx)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
...
    sceneChart.setOnScroll(event -> print(event));
}

public void print (ScrollEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getDeltaY());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

add `onScroll` to your `javafx` element to handle `scroll` `event`
for example here add `onScroll` to `ImageView`

```
<ImageView onScroll="#onScrollImageView" .........../>
```

and `handle` that  in `fxml` `controller` like here:

```
public void onScrollImageView(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
            double deltaY = scrollEvent.getDeltaY();

            if(deltaY<0)
               //scroll up
            if(deltaY>0)
               //scroll down
    }
```

`getDeltaY()`  return the vertical scroll amount. 
and negative value of `getDeltaY()` or positive value means `scroll direction`